# how to make Mysqldatabase converter in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

i want to make Mysql Database converter that can obtain the data from Database A to database B.

both database have same table and column.

how i can make them using c#.

are anyone show me flow or how i can do it

Comment: You might be better off backing up DatabaseA and restoring to DatabaseB. If you need to keep them in sync, you can use MySQL replication services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following steps:

- Execute the query to retrieve the data from database A;
- For every record retrieved, insert a new record into database B.

This mechanism can be automated by automatically creating queries and inserts. To retrieve the tables and fields in a MySQL database, refer to the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html). Using the information retrieved from these tables, you can automatically construct the required queries and migrate an entire database automatically.